# Why 64-bit project in Visual Studio still uses 32-bit static-libraries?

Tags: visual-studio, x86, 64-bit, static-libraries, static-linking

I created a Win32 program in VS2017, and turn into x64 Release Configuration.
I found that input libs in linker that were evaluated with `%(AdditionalDependencies)` still point to those libs in 32-bit.

<del>As a 64-bit program cannot use 32-bit DLLs for some reasons, I think it's the same reasons why it cannot use 32-bit LIBs.</del>

Why 64-bit project in Visual Studio can use 32-bit static-libraries?
Confused and waiting for any suggestions.

[image: Configuration changed but Dependencies didn't]

Comment: *Why 64-bit project in Visual Studio can use 32-bit static-libraries?*  **You can't actually link 32-bit object files into a 64-bit executable**.  IA-32 and x86-64 are as different as MIPS and ARM, as far as compilers and linkers / other parts of the toolchain are concerned.  If your IDE thinks that's going to work, it's setting you up for a link error, at least if you actually call any functions defined in those static libs, or more likely always.

Answer (score 4):

x86 and x86-64 are 2 different architectures with different instruction sets. Each instruction set is like a different language, therefore binaries on those architectures can't be linked together, as one architecture doesn't understand the other's "language". Even with the same instruction set there may be multiple [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) which means sometimes linking two 32-bit objects isn't possible if they use different conventions

Dynamic libraries and static libraries are all... libraries. They have to be linked against the compiled objects at some point (runtime or link time). As above, **linking binaries in different architectures isn't possible** which is why you need 64-bit libraries for 64-bit applications

---

## Edit:

After you included the screenshot it's now clear that you're referring to the system library files. In this case it's just that the **names aren't changed**, the content inside is actually 64-bit. So ***the 64-bit project isn't linked agains 32-bit code***

On 64-bit Windows System32 is the 64-bit system folder, and the 32-bit system binaries are stored in SysWOW64. Files and folders with the `32` suffix will contain 64-bit code

The same thing applies to many other folders and registry keys, because unfortunately bad programmers have hardcoded paths like System32, HKLM\SOFTWARE... for decades and MS couldn't rename them without breaking old code. Therefore 32-bit apps when running on 64-bit Windows will be put under [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) so that they can use the same path and get the correct libraries in the bitness they need